# How one Jhipster application microservices call in another application..?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

I have 1 UAA, 1 gateway and 2 microservices application. How can i call first application rest api to another application.

Comment: Have you read the doc? https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go much deeper in Jhipster, it is call service discovery of other microservice, a time you init jhisper app it will ask you to add microservices, you can go through below links.

[API DOC](https://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/)  , [Example](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you @himeshGoswami